# how to use awk to read a part of line including number of space?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to extract a value using "awk subtring" which should also count the number of spaces without any separator.

For example, below is the input, and I want to extract the "29611", including space,

```
201903011232101029 2961104E3021  223  0 12113  5  15 8288 298233 0  45  0     39    4
```

I used this method, but it used space as a separator:

```
more abbas.dat | awk '{print substr($1,1,16),substr($1,17,25)}'
```

Expected output should be :

```
201903011232101029  2961
```

But it prints only

```
201903011232101029
```

My question is how can we print using "substr" which count spaces?

I know, I can use this command to get the desired output but it is not helpful for my objective

```
more abbas.dat | awk '{print substr($1,1,16),substr($2,1,5)}'
```

Comment: Use `$0` instead of `$1` or `$2`. The value of `$0` represents, in most cases, the original record. That record contains the original amount of spaces. Also, don't use `more` as a command, just pass the file `abbas.dat` directly to `awk`. `more` has a couple of side-issues.

Comment: In an earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568900/how-to-use-awk-to-read-a-part-of-line-including-number-of-space#comment126490557_71568977), you mention that there are a random amount of spaces. From this, it seems that the problem you describe here is ill posed. Could you [edit] your question a bit so you can describe clearly what you want?

Comment: You have accepted an answer which uses `s` as a field separator but your shown samples are NOT having it. Please confirm if your actual file is same as shown samples, if yes then try using other provided solutions also which are written as per your shown samples, cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I think S means "space" in this command. I accepted this one as it is just a command line so it will be helpful for newbies. Never mind, I can accept yours too but that’s a bit complex.

Comment: @user16941410, no that `s` doesn't mean space at all. And trust me with your shown samples mine is NOT complex at all(keeping in mind that you want to catch a varying space also), cheers.

Comment: It's very unclear what you actually want to do, but whatever it is the currently accepted answer doesn't do that as it makes no sense and doesn't produce the output you say you want. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and make sure the expected output you posted is **exactly** the output you expect (including the spaces between the numeric strings) given the input you provided. Posting more than 1 line of sample input/output would probably help.

Comment: Learned a lot… @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Using `match` function of `awk` here to get required output.

***To*** print 1st field followed by varying spaces followed by 5 digits from 2nd field then use following:

```
awk 'match($0,/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+[0-9]{5}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

***OR*** To print 16 letters in 1st field and 5 from second field including varying length of spaces between 1st and 2nd fields:

```
awk 'match($0,/^([0-9]{16})[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]]+)([0-9]{5})/,arr){print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following, considering that your 2nd column first 4 needed values can be anything(eg: digits, alphabets etc).

```
grep -oP '^\S+\s+.{5}' Input_file
```

***OR*** to only match 4 digits in 2nd field have a minor change in above `grep`.

```
grep -oP '^\S+\s+\d{5}' Input_file
```

Comment: I think the `grep` is the best solution as it makes no assumption on the content of the first and second field.

Answer (score 1):

If there is always one space you can use the following command which will print the first group, plus the first 5 character of the second group.
N.B. It's not clear in the question whether you want 4 or 5 characters but that can be adjusted easily.

```
more abbas.dat | awk '{print $1" "substr($2,1,5) }'
```

Comment: There is a random number of spaces, so I want to "substring" based on one such as awk '{substr($1,1,18),substr($1,21,8)}'

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to include "Fs" in your command.

```
more abbas.dat | awk -Fs '{print substr($1,1,16),substr($1,17,25)}'
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you do here. It seems you change the field separator by the character `s`. This is a brilliant move, but it does not explain why you still need two `substr`. Also, without the `-Fs` you could just write `{print substr($0,1,16),substr($0,17,25)}`

Comment: Sure. I check the awk help command. it is mentioned to use -Fs if you also want to count  the space.  copied from awk "-F fs  --field-separator=fs"

Comment: Thanks @Aqeel . This one is a smart way

Comment: @user16941410, ohhhh? I can't believe. This answer haven't worked for me at all and even kvantour has said same thing, could you please do let us know how it worked for you? Since your shown file doesn't have any `s` in it?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated the answer in question. I am also not sure how it works, but actually it works.

Comment: @user16941410, that's not possible with your shown samples, if your actual file is ditto same as shown samples then I advise you to please do check my answer also once, because that is written as per your shown samples only.

Comment: Thanks dear @RavinderSingh13. you are really kind.  Let me update my input in details so It will be helpful for everyone

Comment: @user16941410, sure. So you mean you have `s` in input? Which is not there in samples as of now.

Comment: Setting FS to `s` and then using `$1` makes no sense for this problem and would fail given different input. Also the script simply doesn't produce the expected output from the question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. Brother Here is my input which can separate and include spacing: $ more abbas.dat 201903011232101029 2961104E3021 223 0 12113 5 15 8288 298233 0 45 0 39 4 $ more abbas.dat | awk -Fs '{print substr($1,1,16),substr($1,12,5)}' 2019030112321010 21010

Comment: I do not know my answer will lead to a long discussion. I randomly tried this way and give the output that the user wants. I agreed with @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,24)}' file
201903011232101029 29611
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: There's just SO many different things that could mean and the one line of sample input/output in your question doesn't tell us which it is, nor does the text or code in your question. There's 20 different ways to get the output you posted from the input you posted and it's not at all clear which is the way you actually want/need to handle other input correctly. Think about a use case where my answer doesn't do what you want and then edit your question to include that use case and better describe your requirements.

Comment: Hi Sir, I do not know where I am wrong but this commands works for me:               $ more abbas.dat
201903011232101029 2961104E3021  223  0 12113  5  15 8288 298233 0  45  0     39    4    
              $ more abbas.dat | awk -Fs '{print substr($1,1,16),substr($1,12,5)}'
2019030112321010 21010

Comment: Code that produces the expected output from some sample input is the starting point to a solution, not the end point. In this case, as pointed out by a few other people already, setting FS to `s` makes no sense and so you're getting the same output as if you didn't do `-Fs` and uses `$0` instead of `$1` in the `substr()` but then the code in your comment doesn't match the code in any answer, and now it's using overlapping character ranges and duplicate output substrings (`21010`) which wasn't the case in your question, etc. - it's an answer to a different question than the one you asked.

Comment: That is a really helpful explanation @Ed Morton

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If you update your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output then we could help you come up with the best answer to solve whatever your problem really is.